How do I change XML style to an HTML tag
I have an XML file that I'm converting to HTML with an XSLT version 1.0 stylesheet.
The XML has a text element ExampleText/AStr that contain Run elements, some of which have an attribute named namedStyle set to "Headword in Example". In my output HTML, I want to highlight those elements with HTML <mark> markup.
Here's an example extracted from the input XML:
<ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">Highlighting one piece with fancy style==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">only expected highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">==after highlighted text</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText>

I would like the output HTML for the above XML to contain the following:
Highlighting one piece with fancy style==<mark>only expected highlighted text</mark>==after highlighted text

My XSLT file converts the input XML file into an HTML table with the ExampleText/AStr elements in one of the columns.
It's processing most of the the XML correctly, but doesn't correctly find and transform the elements I mentioned above:
Here is the entire input XML test.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LexExamplePatchSet>
<LexExamplePatch>
<ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">no highlighting</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText>
<LexEntText>
<AUni ws="jii">Entry One</AUni>
</LexEntText>
</LexExamplePatch>
<LexExamplePatch>
<ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">highlighting with html mark ==<mark>highlighted text</mark>== unmarked after</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText>
<LexEntText>
<AUni ws="jii">Entry Two</AUni>
</LexEntText>
</LexExamplePatch>
<LexExamplePatch>
<ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">Highlighting one piece with fancy style==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">only expected highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">==after highlighted text</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText>
<LexEntText>
<AUni ws="jii">Entry Three</AUni>
</LexEntText>
</LexExamplePatch>
<LexExamplePatch>
<ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">Highlighting two pieces with fancy style==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">first expected highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">== between first and second text ==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">second highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">== after the second</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText>
<LexEntText>
<AUni ws="jii">Entry Four</AUni>
</LexEntText>
</LexExamplePatch>
</LexExamplePatchSet>

The XSLT that I wrote doesn't add the <mark> HTML tags correctly, and it leaves the <Run> markup in the HTML. Here's my attempt:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    
    <xsl:template match="LexExamplePatchSet">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Example Sentences (with highlighting)</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>Example Sentences</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Entry</th>
                        <th>Example Sentence</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="LexExamplePatch">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="LexEntText"/>  
                </td>
                <td>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="ExampleText"/>   
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="//LexExamplePatch/ExampleText/AStr/Run[@namedStyle='Headword in Example']">
        <mark><xsl:value-of select="."/></mark>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

I tested the match criteria using xmlstarlet and get the expected result:
$ xmlstarlet sel  -t -m '//LexExamplePatch/ExampleText/AStr/Run[@namedStyle="Headword in Example"]' -v . -n <test.xml
only expected highlighted text
first expected highlighted text
second highlighted text

Here is how I generated the test-result.html file
xsltproc test.xsl test.xml >test-result.html

Here is the resulting HTML test-result.html file without the desired HTML <mark> tags (the only <mark> tags were in the original XML). It also contains some of the original <Run> XML.:
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Example Sentences (with highlighting)</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example Sentences</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Entry</th>
<th>Example Sentence</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry One
</td>
<td><ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">no highlighting</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Two
</td>
<td><ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">highlighting with html mark ==
<mark>highlighted text</mark>== unmarked after</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Three
</td>
<td><ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">Highlighting one piece with fancy style==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">only expected highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">==after highlighted text</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Four
</td>
<td><ExampleText>
<AStr ws="jii">
<Run ws="jii">Highlighting two pieces with fancy style==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">first expected highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">== between first and second text ==</Run>
<Run namedStyle="Headword in Example" ws="jii">second highlighted text</Run>
<Run ws="jii">== after the second</Run>
</AStr>
</ExampleText></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Here is what I would like the HTML to look like test-desired.html:
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Example Sentences (with highlighting)</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example Sentences</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Entry</th>
<th>Example Sentence</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry One
</td>
<td>no highlighting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Two
</td>
<td>highlighting with html mark ==<mark>highlighted text</mark>== unmarked after</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Three
</td>
<td>Highlighting one piece with fancy style==<mark>only expected highlighted text</mark>==after highlighted text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Entry Four
</td>
<td>Highlighting two pieces with fancy style==<mark>first expected highlighted text</mark>== between first and second text ==<mark>second highlighted text</mark>== after the second</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>



I over-simplified the input XML file. I've modified the question to include an additional field (LexEntText) in each LexExamplePatch input XML. This additional field should appear in a separate column in the output HTML file. I've modified the question to include this.
@y.arazim suggested that the HTML output shouldn't include any of the original XML. I've also modified the question to reflect that.
As well, they suggested that I include what I would like the output HTML to look like. I have done so.

It would help to see the exact result you expect to get. It makes very little sense to copy non-HTML elements into an HTML output.
I think this may be the XSLT you're looking for:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/LexExamplePatchSet">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Example Sentences (with highlighting)</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Example Sentences</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Example Sentence</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="LexExamplePatch">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mark | Run[@namedStyle='Headword in Example']">
    <mark>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>   
    </mark>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

When I apply this to your example XML, I get:
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Example Sentences (with highlighting)</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Example Sentences</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Example Sentence</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>no highlighting</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>highlighting with html mark ==
               <mark>highlighted text</mark>== unmarked after</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Highlighting one piece with fancy style==<mark>only expected highlighted text</mark>==after highlighted text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Highlighting two pieces with fancy style==<mark>first expected highlighted text</mark>== between first and second text ==<mark>second highlighted text</mark>== after the second</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>

and in a browser:


At your suggestion, I've removed the XML from the output. I've also added an additional column which will contain an additional field from each LexExamplePatch element.

Please do not change or add to your question after it has been answered.
